# Remapping keys using xkb

Tags: xfce, remapping, xubuntu, xmodmap, xkb

My return key is physically dead.

I'm running xubuntu. I am able to remap the AltGr to return using xmodmap. However when I reload xmodmap, either via shell or automatically during boot, it will hang for 5 minutes. This is a known issue with xfce and xmodmap.

So how would I use xkb to map altgr to return?

(or how would I stop altgr hanging for so long?)

Comment: I can use xkbcomp to swap the keys around, but I can't make the changes persistent.

Comment: if xkbcomp works, you could put it in xinit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xmodmap program works fine for me under Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 when I give it my own map file, but it does hang like you mentioned when I run it under Fedora 20.  The solution I did was to run the following:

```
xmodmap -e "insert your keycode mapping here"
```

You basically call xmodmap for each individual keycode you wish to modify.  It's somewhat of a cumbersome workaround, but it does work.

Comment: that being said, new keyboards are pretty cheap.